# Generar TreeView con Json

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap

Estoy generando un TreeView con un Json, la librería que estoy utilizando es bootstrap-treeview.js.

La estructura del Json que recibo es la siguiente:

```
 data = [{
    "Nivel": 0,
    "NombrePuesto": "Coordinador"
    }, {
    "Nivel": 1,
    "NombrePuesto": "Encargado"
    }, {
    "Nivel": 1,
    "NombrePuesto": "Jefe"
    }, {
    "Nivel": 2,
    "NombrePuesto": "Analista 1"
    }, {
    "Nivel": 2,
    "NombrePuesto": "Analista 2"
    }, {
    "Nivel": 1,
    "NombrePuesto": "Jefe de Controles"
    }, {
    "Nivel": 2,
    "NombrePuesto": "Encargado 1"
    }, {
    "Nivel": 1,
    "NombrePuesto": "Jefe de Supervision"
    }, {
    "Nivel": 2,
    "NombrePuesto": "Tecnico 1"
    }, {
    "Nivel": 3,
    "NombrePuesto": "Tecnico 2"
    }, {
    "Nivel": 4,
    "NombrePuesto": "Tecnico 3"
    }];
```

Y debo convertir el json, en base al nivel del puesto a:

```
 var tree = [{
  text: "Coordinador",
  nodes: [{
      text: "Encargado",

    },
    {
      text: "Jefe",
      nodes: [{
          text: "Analista 1"
        },
        {
          text: "Analista 2"
        }
      ]

    },
    {
      text: "Jefe de Controles",
      nodes: [{
        text: "Encargado 1"
      }]
    },
    {
      text: "Jefe de Supervision",
      nodes: [{
          text: "Tecnico 1"
        },
        {
          text: "Tecnico 2"
        },
        {
          text: "Tecnico 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];
```

He intentado recorrer el Json con un $.each pero no logro generar la estructura correcta ya que siempre me queda con símbolos de más o de menos. Leí que era posible recorrer el Json y hacer push a un array dependiendo el tipo de nivel, pero no logro hacerlo.

La consulta que genera el json tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: Sql]

Si alguien puede ayudarme muchas gracias.

Este es el ejemplo de como debería quedar, pero lo llene a mano no con código.

```js
data = [{
  "Nivel": 0,
  "NombrePuesto": "Coordinador"
}, {
  "Nivel": 1,
  "NombrePuesto": "Encargado"
}, {
  "Nivel": 1,
  "NombrePuesto": "Jefe"
}, {
  "Nivel": 2,
  "NombrePuesto": "Analista 1"
}, {
  "Nivel": 2,
  "NombrePuesto": "Analista 2"
}, {
  "Nivel": 1,
  "NombrePuesto": "Jefe de Controles"
}, {
  "Nivel": 2,
  "NombrePuesto": "Encargado 1"
}, {
  "Nivel": 1,
  "NombrePuesto": "Jefe de Supervision"
}, {
  "Nivel": 2,
  "NombrePuesto": "Tecnico 1"
}, {
  "Nivel": 3,
  "NombrePuesto": "Tecnico 2"
}, {
  "Nivel": 4,
  "NombrePuesto": "Tecnico 3"
}];

var tree = [{
  text: "Coordinador",
  nodes: [{
      text: "Encargado",

    },
    {
      text: "Jefe",
      nodes: [{
          text: "Analista 1"
        },
        {
          text: "Analista 2"
        }
      ]

    },
    {
      text: "Jefe de Controles",
      nodes: [{
        text: "Encargado 1"
      }]
    },
    {
      text: "Jefe de Supervision",
      nodes: [{
          text: "Tecnico 1"
        },
        {
          text: "Tecnico 2"
        },
        {
          text: "Tecnico 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];

/*var tree = '';
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  //console.log(item.Nivel, item.NombrePuesto);
  if (item.Nivel == 0) {
tree += '[{text: "' + item.NombrePuesto + '"';
  }
  if (item.Nivel == 1) {
tree += ', nodes: [{text: "' + item.NombrePuesto + '"}';
  }
  if (item.Nivel >= 2) {
tree += ',{text: "' + item.NombrePuesto + '"}';
  }
});

*/

function cargarTreeView() {
 $.each(data, function(i, item) {
  
  });

  var $TreeV = $('#treeview').treeview({
    data: tree
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  cargarTreeView();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview/master/public/js/bootstrap-treeview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview/master/public/css/bootstrap-treeview.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview/master/public/css/bootstrap-treeview.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div id="treeview" class="treeview">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es nada corto pero acá está la conversión, utilizando el mismo ejemplo que dejaste.

> Luego puedes pasar este Objeto a la funcion cargarTreeView

```js
var data = [{
  "Nivel": 0,
  "NombrePuesto": "Coordinador"
}, {
  "Nivel": 1,
  "NombrePuesto": "Encargado"
}, {
  "Nivel": 1,
  "NombrePuesto": "Jefe"
}, {
  "Nivel": 2,
  "NombrePuesto": "Analista 1"
}, {
  "Nivel": 2,
  "NombrePuesto": "Analista 2"
}, {
  "Nivel": 1,
  "NombrePuesto": "Jefe de Controles"
}, {
  "Nivel": 2,
  "NombrePuesto": "Encargado 1"
}, {
  "Nivel": 1,
  "NombrePuesto": "Jefe de Supervision"
}, {
  "Nivel": 2,
  "NombrePuesto": "Tecnico 1"
}, {
  "Nivel": 3,
  "NombrePuesto": "Tecnico 2"
}, {
  "Nivel": 4,
  "NombrePuesto": "Tecnico 3"
}];

var lastIndex = 0;
var texto = "[{";
var add1 = "";
var add2 = "";
var search = 0;
var i = 0;
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
  
  if (item.Nivel > lastIndex) {
     search = texto.lastIndexOf('}');
     if (search !== -1 && lastIndex != 0) {
        texto = texto.substr(0, search)+", ";
     }
     texto += '"nodes": [';
     
  } else if (lastIndex > item.Nivel) {
     texto = texto.substr(0, texto.length-2);
     texto += "]";
     for (i = 1; i < lastIndex - item.Nivel; i++) {
       texto += "}]";
     }
     texto += "}";
     texto += ",";
  }
  if (item.Nivel > 0){
     add1 = "{";
      add2 = "}";
  }
  texto += add1+'"text": '+'"'+item.NombrePuesto+'"'+add2+', ';
  lastIndex = item.Nivel;
});
texto = texto.substr(0, texto.length-2);
if (lastIndex > 0) {
     texto += "]";
     for (i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
       texto += "}]";
     }
}
//console.log(texto);
var tree = [];
// Puedes luego parsear este a un Object JSON.
try {
   tree = JSON.parse(texto);
}catch (exception) {
   console.log(exception);
}
//console.log(tree);

function cargarTreeView() {    
  var $TreeV = $('#treeview').treeview({
    data: tree
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    cargarTreeView();
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview/master/public/js/bootstrap-treeview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview/master/public/css/bootstrap-treeview.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview/master/public/css/bootstrap-treeview.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div id="treeview" class="treeview">
  </div>
</div>
```

> PD: Eventualmente este código puede ser optimizado.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido de mucho tu respuesta, solo debo hacerle una modificación al código. Para que cuando encuentre un nivel 2,3,4 o mayor no siga generando sub-niveles sino que deje todos los 2 o > en el mismo nivel.

Answer (score 2):

Le he estado dando unas cuantas vueltas y he conseguido generar el `treeview`:

```js
data = [{
  "Nivel": 0,
  "NombrePuesto": "Coordinador"
}, {
  "Nivel": 1,
  "NombrePuesto": "Encargado"
}, {
  "Nivel": 1,
  "NombrePuesto": "Jefe"
}, {
  "Nivel": 2,
  "NombrePuesto": "Analista 1"
}, {
  "Nivel": 2,
  "NombrePuesto": "Analista 2"
}, {
  "Nivel": 1,
  "NombrePuesto": "Jefe de Controles"
}, {
  "Nivel": 2,
  "NombrePuesto": "Encargado 1"
}, {
  "Nivel": 1,
  "NombrePuesto": "Jefe de Supervision"
}, {
  "Nivel": 2,
  "NombrePuesto": "Tecnico 1"
}, {
  "Nivel": 3,
  "NombrePuesto": "Tecnico 2"
}, {
  "Nivel": 4,
  "NombrePuesto": "Tecnico 3"
}];

/*var tree = [{
  text: "Coordinador",
  nodes: [{
  text: "Encargado",

},
{
  text: "Jefe",
  nodes: [{
      text: "Analista 1"
    },
    {
      text: "Analista 2"
    }
  ]

},
{
  text: "Jefe de Controles",
  nodes: [{
    text: "Encargado 1"
  }]
},
{
  text: "Jefe de Supervision",
  nodes: [{
      text: "Tecnico 1"
    },
    {
      text: "Tecnico 2"
    },
    {
      text: "Tecnico 3"
    }
  ]
}
  ]
}];*/

var tree = '';
var nodos = 0;
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  if (item.Nivel == 0) {
tree += '[{"text": "' + item.NombrePuesto + '", "nodes": [';
  nodos=nodos + 1;
  }
  if (item.Nivel == 1) {
   if(data[i+1].Nivel>=2)
   {
    tree += '{"text": "' + item.NombrePuesto + '", "nodes": [';
nodos=nodos+1;
   }
   else
   {
  tree += '{"text": "' + item.NombrePuesto + '"},';
} 
  }
  if (item.Nivel >= 2) {
  if(i<data.length-1)
  {
 if(data[i+1].Nivel>=2)
 {
    tree += '{"text": "' + item.NombrePuesto + '"},';
  }
  else
  {
    tree += '{"text": "' + item.NombrePuesto + '"}]},';
    nodos=nodos - 1;
  }
}
else
{
    tree += '{"text": "' + item.NombrePuesto + '"}]';
}
  }
});

for (j = 0; j < nodos; j++) {
tree+='}]';
} 



function cargarTreeView() {
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  
  });

  var $TreeV = $('#treeview').treeview({
data: JSON.parse(tree) 
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  cargarTreeView();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview/master/public/js/bootstrap-treeview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview/master/public/css/bootstrap-treeview.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview/master/public/css/bootstrap-treeview.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div id="treeview" class="treeview">
  </div>
</div>
```

He tenido que hacer algún cambio como entrecomillar `text` y `nodos`, ver cuál es el nodo siguiente para saber qué generar y el `JSON.parse(tree)` para convertir el string generado a objeto. Tendrás que darle un pulido por si hay más casos de uso (y lo puedes optimizar) pero como idea inicial creo que te puede funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Kiko_L muy agradecido por tu ayuda.