# Recursividad en PHP - Como generar la estructura de datos para bootstrap-treeview

Tags: php, recursión, jstree

Estoy necesitando ayuda para generar la estructura de datos solicitado por bootstrap-treeview (https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview)

En mi Tabla tengo: (id, padre_id, nombre)

Como puedo crear la siguiente estructura utilizando PHP?????

```
var tree = [
  {
    text: "Parent 1",
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Child 1",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Grandchild 1"
          },
          {
            text: "Grandchild 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Child 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 2"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 3"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 4"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 5"
  }
];
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta [Generar TreeView con Json](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153064/generar-treeview-con-json/153176#153176) posible duplicado.